# AMQP/RabbitMQ consumer on NGINX

Tags: nginx, rabbitmq, amqp

Is it possible to have RabbitMQ Consumer listening to a queue for message via AMQP protocol. I am aware that nginx only supports HTTP/s protocol. Was wondering if this can be achieved by using tcp module extension.

I am using nginx as API Gateway and want to do a protocol translation from AMQP to HTTP since all the backend service's are exposed on HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

It would definitely be possible writing your own C extension. nginx is [suitable for TCP proxying](https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module), therefore I don't see any reason why you couldn't send your own TCP packets to RabbitMQ using nginx, and consequently use nginx as a RabbitMQ consumer. It's probably a lot of work to make it run, and even more work to make it stable and reliable, but doable. Do me a favor though, don't do this. There will always be better, more elegant and simpler solution.

HTTP is definitely not suitable for consuming from a queue (in the amqp sense) because you have to keep the socket open while you consume. However, you could write a C extension to publish/retrieve messages to/from RabbitMQ (and apparently, [somebody has already done this](https://github.com/WPMedia/nginx-amqp)). If you're not that much into C or don't want to maintain your own nginx package, you could also write a LUA extension for lua-nginx-module (once again, [somebody seems to have worked in this direction](https://github.com/AlanWangWP/nginx-rabbitmq)). These are PoC for talking to MQ from nginx, but they are not consumers. Both extensions seems to act in the HTTP context, so you need to answer (and close the socket) pretty fast.

However, as far as I know, there isn't any community-driven and well maintained project that would serve this purpose directly or indirectly; you'd have to make and maintain your own extension/client. Moreover, nginx is your current API gateway. Do take the risk into account. Things could go really wrong. Only you can tell whether it is worth the hassle or not, but it's most likely not.

Since you don't gave that much information on what you're exactly looking for, I just answered you on the NGINX/AMQP part. But you might just be looking for an HTTP interface for RabbitMQ. In this case, the [Management Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) might be the way to go. It has a pretty cool [HTTP API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api). Once again, you'd loose every stateful features (like basic consuming, ack/nack/rejects), but that's inherently due to the way HTTP is designed.

Eventually, if you really need a RabbitMQ "basic-"consumer, I would recommend you to write a proper consumer as a separate application and forget about doing this in nginx. That's definitely the best and most supported solution.